# Stuck with terminal commands

Tags: node.js, linux, terminal, server

I have a server running at port 80.I have created endpoints for this server which takes payload and run some terminal commands.So,whenever i am trying to access the endpoint it is throwing an error(cannot cd to the /home/*).

```
let baseDirectory = "/home/xyz/node/";
let cmd = "cd " + baseDirectory;

exec(cmd,function(error,stdout,stderr){
if(error !== null){        
    console.log(error);
    cb("exec_error");
}
else{
    cb(undefined,"success");
}
});
```

Comment: have you checked your command in command prompt, i think u need to concatenate string for cmd and then need to use it `let cmd = "cd " + baseDirectory;`

Comment: yeah i did @kgangadhar

Comment: Don't you think `let cmd = cd baseDirectory;` should be `let cmd = "cd " + baseDirectory;`

Comment: 1. is it "cannot cd to /home/*" or "cannot cd to /home/xyz/node/" ?? 2. check your permissions, if you run your app using a different user than xyz, you probably dont have permission to access it.